# What's wrong with the formatting in this C++ program?

Tags: c++

Recently I've asked a question regarding this c++ program that I made and I got scolded for the bad formatting but nobody explicitly described how I should format it. I know it's bad, I'm a beginner, but if someone there is someone kind enough to explain to me what is wrong with the program(sorry if too ambiguous), that would be great. Thanks.

This is a **working** program that reads numbers from "bac.txt" and returns the 2 digit number/numbers (10,11,12,...,99) that appear most frequently. For example if the file "bac.txt" contains 393 17775787 72194942 12121774 it will return 77 and 21.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

    int counter(int n)
    {
        int i = 0, j = 0;
        char x1 = n / 10 + '0';
        char x2 = n % 10 + '0';
        char a;
        char b;

        fstream fisier("bac.txt", fstream::in);
        fisier >> b;
        while (fisier >> a) {
            if (b == x1 && a == x2)
                i++;
            b = a;
        }
        return i;
    }

    int main()
    {
        int v[101];
        int i, maxim = 0, nr;
        for (i = 10; i < 100; i++) {
            v[i] = counter(i);
            if (v[i] > maxim)
                maxim = v[i];
        }

        for (i = 10; i < 100; i++)
            if (v[i] == maxim)
                cout << i<<" ";
    }
```

Comment: If your code actually works and you want it reviewed, the right site is: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: I think no one is forced to explicitly tell or write code for others. Most of your "problem", like in your previous post here in SO, can be dismissed by reading a good tutorial of C++. There are a lot out there.

Comment: Rather than referring the question, it's best to answer it anyway. Your functions are indented. There's no need to indent your functions, but you should still indent your function definitions. As for the curly-braces, it's fine to have the first inline or begun in the next line.  Another cause of concern is that you are sharing your iterator `i`. It's better to have the iterator `i` declared within the `for` loop.

Comment: This is not formatted the way your earlier question was.

Comment: The formatting is not bad. The only thing is that you may want to align the code to `using namespace std;`. The current version is shifted to the right, you should probably shift it to the left.

Comment: Formatting is generally subjective, where to put spaces and newlines and such. If the person who scolded you is somebody you work for, then they should show you the style guide they expect. Otherwise, if it's legible and compiles and if your code is coherent in its choice of style, then you're not in the wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it looks good. It all depends, on who will read it. Often companies and projects have a really strict code style. It usually looks something like this:

```
if( var1 == var2 ) {
   while( ...){
      doSomething();
      // Capitalize your comments, and end with a period.
   }
} else {
  ...
}
```

I think this is called java-style.
Or sometimes:

```
if( var1 == var2 )
{
   while( ...)
   {
      doSomething();
      // Capitalize your comments, and end with a period.
   }
}
else
{
   ...
}
```

Where this is the c-style. 
This is mostly a matter of preference (of your boss).

If you not working together with people, or posting your code (on SO for instance), it is less important of course. Personally i like this syntax:

```
for ( int x=0; x < 100; x++)
for ( int y=0; y < 100; y++)
{    
  doSomething();
}
```

It does look more neat, but i would never really dare post it to somewhere, or push it to a collaborative project, because a lot of people tend to get confused.

And yes, it is important, it can cause bugs that deserve their [own website](https://gotofail.com/).

Comment: Minus 1. you misspelled period.                   just kidding, it wasn't me

Comment: haha, this reminds me of "software quality" course. With stuff like "your comment doesn't end with a period" ;)

Comment: It does make me wonder why the downvote without explanation.

Comment: Your answer is fine on another site like CR, not on this site - it's not useful IOW. And so is the question. Q/As that are not useful are to be downvoted, since it's what they're for. (I didn't, btw)

Comment: The mere fact that OPs code is working, doesn't take away that he thinks something is wrong with it. And i think it is a nice oportunity to have a discussion about code-style. Since there are a lot of questions out there where there is "random hate" just about style. And I think he just really wanted to know about this.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your previous question, the code you showed is not formatted the same way as in your last question.

Your last question's code looked like:

[image]

However, your current questions code looks formatted okay (there are minor issues, like the toplevel indentation, though).